# Foreign key fails laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm getting an error `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint` when a user tries to add another product in wishlist and when a user tries to add the product which is already in wishlist, also if a user add product 1 to wishlist, it add a different product which I haven't clicked. How can I make user add many and chosen product in wishlist ?

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $wishlists = Wishlist::with('product')
    ->where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->paginate(6);
     return view('front.wishlist', compact('user', 'wishlists'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'user_id'=>'required',
        'product_id' =>'required',
       ));

       $status=Wishlist::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
       ->where('product_id',$request->product_id)
       ->first();

       if(isset($status->user_id) and isset($request->product_id))
          {
              return redirect()->back()->with('flash_messaged', 'This item is already in your
              wishlist!');
          }
          else
          {
              $wishlist = new Wishlist;

              $wishlist->user_id = $request->user_id;
              $wishlist->product_id = $request->product_id;
              $wishlist->save();

              return redirect()->back();
          }

}
```

The  button ( add to wishlist)

```
<form action="{{route('wishlist.store')}}"  method="post">
{{csrf_field()}}
<input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}" />
<input name="product_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}" />
</form>
```

Wishlist.php

```
  class Wishlist extends Model
{

protected $table = "wishlists";
protected $fillable=['product_id','user_id'];

public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function product(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
}
```

Comment: Your structure should be a many to many between wishlists and products. Many products should be able to be on one wishlist.

Comment: You mean this line `return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');` should be `return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'product_id');` @thisiskelvin

Comment: It should be `$this->belongsToMany(Product::class)`, then you will need to make a pivot table for the `wishlist_product`